# Google Cloud Functions can't use Pub/Sub dead-letter topic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

It seems GCP Cloud Functions always ACK Pubsub PUSH messages when invoked, even if function crashes or fails.

This prevents the use of the new Pub/Sub "dead-letter" topic feature, which required message delivery to fail before forwarding it to a different topic.
Presently, messages never fail.

Is there a way to utilize "dead-letter topic" or pubsub re-delivery with Cloud Functions?
Apart for setting the "retry" flag on the function itself, that doesn't solve this issue.

Comment: You mean that you have a push subscription? And the function error code is 400, 500 or empty in case of crash?

Comment: Yes @guillaumeblaquiere, the Cloud Function is registered as a push subscription (google-defined when setting function trigger to pubsub topic).
The error code is 500 I believe, but as it's a "background" type func with pubsub trigger the error is not defined and returned from the function itself, but from google invoking wrapper (as opposed to http-type functions where the user controls return code)

Answer (score 1):

A push subscription impies 2 things:

- create your function in  --trigger-http mode
- create a push PUSH subscription that use the Cloud Functions URL.

Here you have created a function in --trigger-topic mode, it's a background function.

You have [here what you have to do for marking the function as failed](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries#why_background_functions_fail_to_complete).

*Share your code if you need more help*

Comment: A backgroud function created with --trigger-topic mode is still a PUSH subscription.
Looking at the pubsub topic we can see a subscriber was created for the function.
Also, setting retry behavior for the function is -not- a pubsub re-transmission, and will not allow the use of pubsub "dead-letter" topic.

Comment: You're right though - dead-letter and re-transmission works with HTTP type functions.
But it doesn't with Background type functions.

Answer (score 0):

One way that this can be handled (until GCP starts supporting manual acknowledgement for cloud function) is by re-queueing to the same topic with the retry count incremented in case of failure. You can store the retry counts in the payload itself like:

```
{
  "retry_count": 1,
  "data": {...}
}
```

Also to avoid the a faulty message being retried permanently, you can configure it to push to the dead-letter instead if the retry attempts > x.

This only solved the problem if the topi has only one subscriber though.

Comment: When implemented in this fashion it is also possible to keep the original data in message intact but still add retry_count by using an attribute - https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#using_attributes